# Primary color declared in colorScheme and ThemeData in Flutter

Tags: flutter, colors, themes

I was following the Material Design components and at the bottom, there was a Theming section for every component.

Here's the *ThemeData* code,

```
final ThemeData base = ThemeData.light();
return base.copyWith(
  colorScheme: _shrineColorScheme, 
  toggleableActiveColor: shrinePink400,
  accentColor: shrineBrown900,
  primaryColor: shrinePink100,  //defines primary
  buttonColor: shrinePink100,
  scaffoldBackgroundColor: shrineBackgroundWhite,
  cardColor: shrineBackgroundWhite,
  textSelectionColor: shrinePink100,
  errorColor: shrineErrorRed,
  primaryIconTheme: _customIconTheme(base.iconTheme),
  textTheme: _buildShrineTextTheme(base.textTheme),
  primaryTextTheme: _buildShrineTextTheme(base.primaryTextTheme),
  accentTextTheme: _buildShrineTextTheme(base.accentTextTheme),
  iconTheme: _customIconTheme(base.iconTheme),
);
}
```

Here's the definition of the *ColorScheme*,

```
const ColorScheme _shrineColorScheme = ColorScheme(
 primary: shrinePink400,  //defines primary
 primaryVariant: shrineBrown900,
 secondary: shrinePink50,
 secondaryVariant: shrineBrown900,
 surface: shrineSurfaceWhite,
 background: shrineBackgroundWhite,
 error: shrineErrorRed,
 onPrimary: shrineBrown900,
 onSecondary: shrineBrown900,
 onSurface: shrineBrown900,
 onBackground: shrineBrown900,
 onError: shrineSurfaceWhite,
 brightness: Brightness.light,
);
```

Here the value of the *primary* color is set twice. Why is that? We already defined *primary* in the *ColorScheme* so why bother doing it in *ThemeData*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although they have the exact same name, but they are in two different classes, basically there are two classes, `ThemeData` and `ColorScheme`. `ThemeData` is one holding all of your theme settings, and the one controlling how the app will look, but `ColorScheme` is just a set of colors that you create to easily maintain the app's colors. Notice that ThemeData class has a parameter colorScheme,
so you can create your own colorScheme and add it to the ThemeData object.

the `primaryColor` in `ThemeData` is the primary color for all your application, and you can access it through this line:

```
Theme.of(context).primaryColor
```

the `primary` in `ColorScheme`, is just the primaryColor for that colorScheme object, and you can also access it by using that line:

```
Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary
```

##### Note

all of widgets styling inherits from colors or themes from `ThemeData` (defined in `MaterialApp`) not `ColorScheme`, colorScheme is just extra colors that you define to use whether in ThemeData or anywhere across the app.

so colorScheme will only affect widgets colors only if you use these colors in ThemeData, like this:

```
final ThemeData base = ThemeData.light();
return base.copyWith(
  colorScheme: _shrineColorScheme, 
  accentColor: _shrineColorScheme.secondary,
  primaryColor: _shrineColorScheme.primary, 
  scaffoldBackgroundColor: _shrineColorScheme.background,
);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the information but I still have some issues. If I define my own ```colorScheme``` and without ```primary``` in my ```ThemeData```, what happens is that it affects my Buttons and FAB but my AppBar and Switch still uses the default Material blue color. But to fix this I have to define ```primary```  and ```toggleActiveColor``` in my ```ThemeData```. So I'm finding this a bit inconsistent.

Comment: all of widget styling inherits from colors or themes from ThemeData you define in MaterialApp, not ColorScheme, colorScheme is just extra colors that you define to use whether in ThemeData or anywhere across the app, i have updated the answer

Comment: Yeah thanks i got it now. Examples do really help.

Comment: if this is the answer you were looking for, kindly accept it as the right answer.

Comment: very helpful information. Thanks you so much!!!

Answer (score 2):

A comment in the ThemeData object provides some clarity:

> [colorScheme] is the preferred way to configure colors. The other
> color properties (as well as primaryColorBrightness, and
> primarySwatch) will gradually be phased out, see
> https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/91772.

So for now, I'd recommend setting the colorScheme property using your ColorScheme object and then referencing the values in that object in the ThemeData properties, like primaryColor, focusColor, etc.